# How to use list.index() on a list with duplicate items?

Tags: python, list, indexing

How can I find the index of an element of a list which may contain duplicate items?
This is my code:

```
def as_str(L):
    string = "("
    for element in L:
        string += str(element)
        if L.index(element) < len(L) - 1:
            string += ", "
    string += ")"
    return string
```

which doesn't work if the list contains duplicate items.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, if you want to get a proper answer you need to update your question with the code that you have tried so far and tell us about the problems. Or you can add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about what you want to do and explain about the dark points.

Comment: This was closed as “unclear what you’re asking.” Now that it’s clear, it’s a candidate for reopening, but I’m going to vote against that because it’s now what I call a “gimme-teh-codez” question. Anyway, you got your answer. This note is just for your edification. Please read the help files to see what are considered good and bad questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), e.g.:

```
def as_str(L):
    return "({})".format(", ".join([str(x) for x in L]))
```

Addressing your comment, `L.index` takes optional 'start' and 'stop' parameters that you could use to search a range of indexes (e.g. in a loop).

Comment: Not sure if there's actually a scenario in which I'd need this, but is there an alternate solution to this problem that could be applied to other instances of trying to call the index of a possible duplicate?

Comment: @Paco: one way is to use the 3-argument form of `L.index` (see the update).

Comment: @PacoPoler: If the goal is to do something different on the last element in a loop, don't have every element check if it's the last element with `index`. That means `O(n)` lookups for every element (and failures with duplicates as you noted). If it's absolutely necessary, and the input is a sequence (so you can slice it), something as simple as processing `L[:-1]` in the loop, then explicitly handling `L[-1]` after the loop would be enough. Or conversely, handling `L[0]` before the loop, then looping over `L[1:]` and having each loop do the "between elements" work before processing each item.